# createrepo using --split option for a multi CD distribution

Tags: linux, centos, installation

I am trying to create a customized CentOS multi CD installation.  Our current distribution just grew past the size of a CD.  Sure, you can just burn it on a DVD.  Well, we have customers with old machines that do not support DVDs so I have to create a distribution on 2 CDs.  So far, I've found createrepo using the --split option but cannot find any good examples on how to make this work correctly.  From the man page for createrepo:

```
   --split
          Run  in  split  media mode. Rather than pass a single directory,
          take a set of directories corresponding to different volumes  in
          a media set.
```

Here is the **createrepo** command:

```
  echo "Creating the repository..."
  discinfo=`head -1 $OS_BASE/.discinfo`
  createrepo -v --split -u "media://$discinfo" -g repodata/comps.xml $ISO $ISO_2
```

NOTE: ISO (Disc 1) and ISO_2 (Disc 2) represent build directories that have RPMs copied to them before createrepo is executed.

RPM dir for CentOS 5: $ISO/CentOS

RPM dir for CentOS 6: $ISO/Packages

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure what to expect from using **--split** option with **createrepo**.  I think I'm heading in the right direction using **--split** with **createrepo** but I am not quite sure.

Any ideas on how to properly build a multi-CD dist??  I can't seem to find any good examples.

*** After the problem was solved ***

createrepo --split will look at all the RPMs in your build directories and will create the appropriate XML files in repodata dir on disc1 of the installation.  These XML files will tell anaconda during an install what installation disc they are on and knows based on this to ask you to insert a certain CD.  Make sure your .discinfo file on line 4 (Disc # Line) is set correctly for disc 1 and 2.

I ended up only using the pkorder script to decide what RPMs I should put on disc2.  I also notice and CentOS 6 does not have a pkgorder script so I won't be able to use it going forward.  Will probably have to rework my installation at that point to use the other scripts described in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain but I believe you need to use the `pkgorder` and then `splittree.py` scripts to generate the split RPMs directories then you can run `createrepo` in `--split` mode across them and then run `buildinstall`/etc. on each RPM directory/etc. in sequence.

Comment: I started to use pkgorder so I can run splittree.py but am running into a bug (I think): \nTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/anaconda-runtime/pkgorder", line 32, in ?
    from yuminstall import YumSorter
  File "/usr/lib/anaconda/yuminstall.py", line 32, in ?
    from packages import recreateInitrd
  File "/usr/lib/anaconda/packages.py", line 27, in ?
    import fsset
  File "/usr/lib/anaconda/fsset.py", line 35, in ?
    import bootyutil
ImportError: No module named bootyutil

Comment: I fixed the problem by editing /usr/lib/anaconda-runtime/pkgorder script and adding "sys.path.append("/usr/lib/booty")" after the import statements at the top. So, I'll try running pkgorder now.

Comment: pkgorder <toppath> <arch> <productpath>
<arch>: use rpm architecture for tree, eg i686 -- The only problem here is I have no idea what <toppath> or <productpath> should be???

Comment: Looks like `toppath` is the source repository directory (used as `baseurl` in a yum config file) and `product` is the path under `toppath` where the RPMs live (either directly or under an additional `RPMS` directory).

Comment: Can't get pkgorder to work..It's a piece of crap scrip (at least in CentOS 5.9).  Will try to make it work when we upgrade our build server.  So, I created 2 iso build dirs and manually copied OS rpms to ISO 1 and ISO 2 dirs).  Then I ran createrepo with --split passing both ISO dirs to it and it created the files needed to determine what RPMS are on which disc.  I'll post a reply to this problem with more details.  THX!!

Comment: pkgorder isn't a complicated script, what about it isn't working? It looks like it requires group information to be set up correctly though. So it might be a bit too specialized for your scenario.

Comment: I just got pkgorder to work correctly!! Not sure what the problem was but maybe my environment was screwed up earlier.  So, I copied all the RPMs I needed from the CentOS (6.5) install to /var/tmp/Packages, then I ran '/usr/lib/anaconda-runtime/pkgorder "/var/tmp" i686 "Packages" > rpmorder.txt' and it worked.  On to splittree now.